# MYSQL DESC LIMIT Variable

Tags: php, mysql

I try to run this code

```
$anzahl_neu_ds = $num_rows_after - $num_rows;
    $neue_logs = "SELECT * FROM `logs` WHERE Seitenname = '$val' Order by `Date/Time` DESC LIMIT $anzahl_neu_ds;";
    $ergebnis = mysql_query($neue_logs)
            OR die("Error: $ergebnis <br>".mysql_error());
```

but i only get 1 result. Is it right how i inserted the `$anzahl_neu_ds` next to DESC LIMIT? 
Or how do I insert a Variable inside a Query?

Thanks for helping:

Kind Regards, 
Kevin

Comment: I think, this is because the value of `$anzahl_neu_ds` is 1.

Comment: and, use mysqli or PDO instead mysql, because mysql functions are deprecated. Avoid sql injections by escaping your strings.

Comment: Do you really have a field name of `Date/Time`?

Comment: Echo the value of `$anzahl_neu_ds` like this `echo $anzahl_neu_ds;` add this line before the select query. Then you will know if that value is the reson for only getting 1 row in the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only doing a single mysql_query and not fetching the result as an array. Try using the following code:

```html
$anzahl_neu_ds = $num_rows_after - $num_rows;
    $neue_logs = "SELECT * FROM `logs` WHERE Seitenname = '$val' Order by `Date/Time` DESC LIMIT $anzahl_neu_ds";
    while($ergebnis = mysql_fetch_array($neue_logs)){
      echo $ergebnis[0].'<br/>';
    }
```